# How to break a loop inside a custom made Tensorflow model (using Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm building a machine learning application in Tensorflow 2.0.
I try to optimize the computitional efficiency by breaking a for-loop (if a condition is met) when iterating over facts inside the call function, but it returns an error saying:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with u/tf.function.
>   (I've also tried adding a tf function the call method

Anyone know how to break a for-loop inside the call function in a custom tensorflow model and do logic?

My code

```py
def call(self, inputs, questions):
    episode = tf.zeros(shape=(self.batch_size, self.units))
    memory = questions
    facts = self.split(self.transpose(self.cast(inputs, tf.float32), perm?(1,0,2)), self.facts_len)

    for _ in range(self.passes):
        for c in facts:
            c = tf.squeeze(c)
            g = self.attention(c, memory, questions)

            episode = (
                g * self.rnn(tf.expand_dims(c,-1), memory)[1] + (1-g) * episode
            )

        # Generates next memory
        _, memory = self.rnn(self.expand(episode, -1), memory)
    return memory
```

Comment: post full model summary.

Comment: Please post your code and tell us what you have tried up till now. For instance do you know the "break" command? Have you used it? We cannot answer such questions without the full information provided by you. Please attach all the required information next time.....

Comment: @neelg What about now?

Comment: I would suggest providing a standalone code to reproduce the issue. Generally speaking, one way to create a loop that can be broken is to use a `tf.while_loop`. For example, in your case, the condition for `tf.while_loop` may be that `self.passes` is reached or something happens to `facts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `break` inside your logic. Keras applies autograph to `call`, so it should work, but my guess is that you need to change the outer loop: `for _ in tf.range(self.passes)`, and if the break is inside the inner loop, make sure `facts` is a Tensor as well.

See this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#use_python_control_flow) and the [reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/control_flow.md#break-statements) focs for more details.